# Remove or add extra class on click jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, html, click

I'm pretty much trying to toggle the extra preference added in the class "orange" by clicking the div. It adds the class without any issues but I can't remove it by clicking once more.

```
$("div.hidden").click(function(){
   $(this).addClass("orange");
});

$("div.orange").click(function(){
   $(this).removeClass("orange");
});


<div class="hidden"></div>

.hidden{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#ccc;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    margin-right:5px;
}

.orange {background-color:#F90;}
```

When I click the div box it changes to class="hidden orange"

Because of this I also tried

```
$("div.hidden orange").click(function(){
   $(this).removeClass("orange");
});
```

To simply strip the "hidden orange" from "orange" and leave it as it was to begin with, but it didn't work.

What is the proper way of toggling a class after an exisiting one?

Comment: Please don't delete your question content. It should remain for future users to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("div").click(function(){
   $(this).toggleClass("orange");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if it has the `orange` class and toggle it.

```
var $div = $('div.hidden');
if ($('div.hidden').hasClass('orange')) {
    $div.removeClass('orange');
}
else $div.addClass('orange');
```

I assign your div to a `$div` variable so I'm not constantly searching for it.

The `.toggleClass()` suggested by Shuping is also a good solution, providing you don't want to run any other scripts depending on whether the `div` has the `orange` class or not.

`addClass()`: http://api.jquery.com/addClass/
`hasClass()`: http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/
`removeClass()`: http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the event handler that removes that class doesn't work, is that it's not applied to the element. At the time that you bind the events, there is no element with the class `orange`, so that event handler won't be bound to any element.

You could use a delegate, so that you could handle that event on the element although it doesn't exist yet, but you still needed to keep the first event from triggering all the time, which means that you would have to introduce something like another class just to keep track of the state of the element.

If you do it in single event handler, you can use the class itself to track the state:

```
$("div.hidden").click(function(){
  if ($(this).hasClass("orange")) {
    $(this).removeClass("orange");
  } else {
    $(this).addClass("orange");
  }
});
```

Or you can use the `toggleClass` method that does the same:

```
$("div.hidden").click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("orange");
});
```

The reason that the `div.hidden orange` selector didn't do anything, is because it would match an `<orange>` tag inside the div, not the div with two classes. To match that you would use the selector `div.hidden.orange`, but that would still not match any element when the events are bound, as the `orange` class is added later.